# Spring Data JPA: Handling inherited property of other entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, kotlin

The Situation:
(classes being entities)

- **class1** has *property* of type **class2**
- **subclass1** (inherits from **class1**) uses type **subclass2** (inherits from **class2**)  for *property*
- **subclass2** has a *property2* that **class2** has not

How can i achieve this in subclass1Repository:

```
findByProperty_property2(xx)
```

Obviously i get "No property "property2" found for type **class1**, Traversed path: **class2**.property2.

Obviously JPA does not know that *property* is of type **subclass2**.

```
@Entity
open class Class1 constructor(
        @ManyToOne property: Class2
)

@Entity
open class Class 2 constructor() {

}

@Entity
open class subclass1 constructor(
        property: Subclass2
):Class1(property = property)


@Entity
open class subclass2 constructor(
        property2: Double
):Class2(..)


interface subclass1Repository: JpaRepository<Subclass1, Long>{
fun findByProperty_property2(prop2:Double): List<Subclass1>
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. There's no such thing as overriding properties in Java. Only methods can be overridden.

Comment: Rather than overriding, did you use generic types?

Comment: @JBNizet: Posted it(Kotlin though)

Comment: @Al1: I did not, i do not know how to do that here

Comment: Use the TREAT JPQL operator, described in the JPA specifications (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html). Example from the specs: `SELECT b.name, b.ISBN
    FROM Order o JOIN TREAT(o.product AS Book) b`

Comment: Thanks Nizet, that should do it

Answer (score 0):

You want to map `subclass1` and `subclass2`? I was little bit lost with your question ... but hope this have value for you.

```
@Entity
public class Foo1 {
@Id
private int id; // primary key is great to have for map tables.
  @ManyToMany // or something 
  @JoinTables(...
  private List<Foo2> foo2;
}

@Entity
public class Foo2 {
  @Id
  private int id;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="foo2")
  private List<Foo1> foo1;

}
```

create getters and setters.

---

Repository for foo2:

```
public interface Foo2Repository extends CrudRepository<Foo2, Long> {
    Foo2 findBySomeValue(Double doubleValue);
```

You can create @Service class for method:

```
@Service
public class FooService {
  @Autowired
  private Foo2Repository foo2Repository;

public List<Foo1> ListMyFoo(Double doubleValue) {
  return this.yourInterface.findBySomeValue(doubleValue).getFoo1();

}
```

It returs you a List based Foo2 SomeValue is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i fear the issue is more complex than that